# Processbuilder unable to find files while running C++ executable

Tags: java, c++, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a C++ executable from Java 1.8 using ProcessBuilder in Linux. The executable takes two filenames as parameters which are read for further processing. The Java code is as follows:

```
        public static void main(String args[]){

        String rootDir = "/home/rtuk/qw_simp/";
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(rootDir + "qw_simple", "Photo1.jpg","Photo2.jpg");

        process.directory(new File(rootDir));
        Process p = process.start();
        int err=p.waitFor();
        InputStream is = p.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

However, the C++ executable is not able to find the files that are passed as parameters and errors specifying that the files are not found.
What could be the problem here? I tried explicitly setting the absolute path for both the arguments, but that also didnt work.

Comment: And just to be sure: you printed the java-side names, so that you are sure you are really passing the correct filenames? And you are also printing the arguments that your binary is called with, to be sure that the receiving side sees the expected input?

Comment: Absolute paths for arguments should work. Maybe the problem is that first argument has excessive space character in the end?

Comment: Yes Jagermeister, I've tried that as well.
@gudok sorry but that was a typo when i put in the code here.
I'm not sure why i got the downvote though. If someone could suggest why, I can improve myself from the next question i post.
Thanks